# Renaming columns of dataframe with values from another dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

so I have a dataframe that roughly looks like this:

```
name1   name2   name3
123     456     678
123     456     678
123     456     678
```

and another dataframe that looks like this

```
name2  abc
name3  cdf
name1  fgh
```

Is there any way I can make the first dataframe column names like this:

```
fgh     abc     cdf
123     456     678
123     456     678
123     456     678
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` by `Series` with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `index` by column `A`:

```
print (df2)
       A    B
0  name2  abc
1  name3  cdf
2  name1  fgh

df1 = df1.rename(columns=df2.set_index('A')['B'])
print (df1)
   fgh  abc  cdf
0  123  456  678
1  123  456  678
2  123  456  678
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.set_index('A')['B'])
A
name2    abc
name3    cdf
name1    fgh
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Or by `dictionary` created by `zip`:

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.A, df2.B)))
```

**Detail**:

```
print (dict(zip(df2.A, df2.B)))
{'name3': 'cdf', 'name1': 'fgh', 'name2': 'abc'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `Series` `get` and assign it back

```
df.columns=s.get(df.columns)
df
Out[223]: 
s1  fgh  abc  cdf
0   123  456  678
1   123  456  678
2   123  456  678
```